# Resolution changes after nvidia proprietary drivers installed

Tags: display, release-hera, nvidia, resolution, proprietary

After installing nvidia 390 drivers I rebooted to find my screen locked to a 1280x1024 resolution, with no option to change it. What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Which nvidia card do you have? Don't you have the options to change the resolution in 'Nvidia Settings'? If you choose third party software for graphics and Wi-Fi hardware when you install eOS 5.1 therer's no need to install the driver manually and it will install the correct driver.You may have installed the wrong driver.

How did you install the nvidia driver?

[image]

Comment: No option to change resolution from nvidia settings. I installed the drivers from Appcenter. I'm using a GTX 560

Comment: OTry this. Uninstall the nvidia driver first (via appcenter). or by command: _sudo apt-get purge nvidia*_ then _sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall_ then _sudo reboot_

Comment: No luck. I tried a fresh install of hera next, then installed the nvidia driver. Everything worked perfectly until all the other updates were installed, then the borked resolution. And returning to the nouveau driver had no effect